# Required attribute is not working properly

Tags: c#, validation, model, attributes, required

Please Help..

I used Required attribute data annotation to validate a field for 'Name'. but after entering the Name also, its showing as 'Name is Required'.
I don't know why the Required attribute is not triggering properly. I am using this in C# only using model.

Kindly help me.

Thanks,
Goutam

Comment: Hello Welcom to Stackoverflow please read our [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please edit your answer with your code so we can see what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your problem but this should be the general steps in how to use validation.

First step is to add this piece of code

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your message here")]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

Then where you want to run the validation you use

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //Your code if the field is invalid
}else
{
    //Your code if the field is valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  But I used as same. Then also, after entering name in Name field, its showing the Error Message only.

Comment: Okay, if you post a bit of code so we can see more clearly what the problem is, it will be easier to help